# What are the different personalities of Civilization V leaders?

Tags: civilization-5

I've noticed different leaders in Civilization V have different "personalities" - i.e. different ways of gameplay and different ways of conducting diplomacy. For example, Russia and Mongolia are very fond of expanding, while Gandhi emphasizes culture and happiness; the English build a lot of naval units; it seems like it's easy to convince Alexander to go to war; China is fond of science victory; etc.

These things are important to know when dealing with other civilizations and when planning long-term strategies. Can anyone provide a rough list of these "personalities", or redirect me to somewhere that lists them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The flavors of the Civilization V leaders are listed in XML files in the folder `Assets\Gameplay\XML\Leaders`. There is one file per leader.

Each flavor like e.g. FLAVOR_SCIENCE or FLAVOR_GROWTH has a value associated with it, the higher that value is the more the AI values that flavor and focuses on it.

The developers also stated that those flavors are modified randomly a bit when a new game is started, you can't count on them being always the same.

There are also diplomacy modifiers in those files, but we can only guess what those exactly mean.